# Generalize multiple for loops

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

```
var terms = [Privacy(), Search(), Stores()]
```

Each of these classes have their own implementations of trackScreen(), trackBanners() etc.,

Currently in the class that has functions calling each of these classes’ implementations of trackScreen() etc.,

```
func trackScreen(screenName: String) {
    for term in terms {
        term.trackScreen(screenName)
    }
}

func trackBanner(banner: UIImage) {
    for term in terms {
        term.trackBanner(banner)
    }
}
```

How do I not repeat the “for term in terms” for each function, but still have each term call its own implementation of those methods?

Comment: make the `foreground/background/launch` part a parameter to a single "track app event" function

Comment: @Alexander could you exemplify how to send a method as a parameter here?

Comment: The functions you've shown here don't have a result; so what do you mean "use the result in each function?" What does the calling code look like, and what would you wish it to look like? The obvious way to make this one loop is to make it one loop that calls `.trackAppforegroud(); .trackAppBackground(); .trakAppLaunch()`. What doesn't that do that you want to do?

Comment: @jayn I don't have any idea what you're actually trying to achieve, so it's hard to prescribe a solution. What's term? What's being tracked? Are all terms being tracked in every way? What does that even mean?

Comment: @Alexander Terms is an array of tracking terms and each tracking term has its own implementation of trackAppForeground() etc.,

Comment: So can't you just combine all 3 calls into one loop body? `for term in terms { term.trackX(); term.trackY(); term.trackZ() }`

Comment: Edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the `for`'s if you want every method to forward the calls. You can't get rid of some "duplicate" code if you want to forward the actions to the contents of the array. You can however reduce the quantity of the same code by using `forEach`:

```
func trackScreen(screenName: String) {
    terms.forEach { $0.trackScreen(screenName) }
}

func trackBanner(banner: UIImage) {
    terms.forEach { $0.trackBanner(banner) }
}
```

You can take it a little bit further by adding an extension over `Sequence`:

```
extension Sequence {
    func perform<T>(_ arg: T, _ f: (Element) -> (T) -> Void) -> Void {
        forEach { f($0)(arg) }
    }
}
```

, and use it in your methods:

```
func trackScreen(screenName: String) {
    terms.perform(screenName, BaseClass.trackScreen }
}

func trackBanner(banner: UIImage) {
    terms.perform(screenName, BaseClass.trackBanner }
}
```

, but that's not much of a gain over the first explicit approach, and you still have duplicated code - the `perform` call.

Basically if you need to do the same operation in different places, with different context, then you'll run into some code duplication, you can't avoid this.